# How to create airflow DAG that cleans meta database

Tags: airflow

Using Airflow 2.3.4 we are trying to create a DAG that cleans the meta database.
Following this [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/usage-cli.html#cli-db-clean) for the db clean command.

Dag looks like:

```
... DAG and arguments ...


CLEAN_BEFORE_TIMESTAMP = now().subtract(days= 60).to_date_string()

with dag:

    db_clean = BashOperator(
            task_id='db_clean',
            bash_command="""airflow db clean --clean-before-timestamp $clean_before_timestamp -y""",
            env = {
                "clean_before_timestamp": CLEAN_BEFORE_TIMESTAMP,
                "PATH": os.getenv("PATH")
            }
            )
            
    
    db_clean
```

The dag runs, and is marked successful. However it seems to not find the tables in the database.
Error is:

```
[2022-10-13T08:16:36.768+0000] {subprocess.py:62} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
 /tmp
[2022-10-13T08:16:36.769+0000] {subprocess.py:74} INFO - Running command: ['/bin/bash', '-c', 'airflow db clean --clean-before-timestamp $clean_before_timestamp -y']
[2022-10-13T08:16:36.786+0000] {subprocess.py:85} INFO - Output:
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.169+0000] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - [[34m2022-10-13 08:16:39,169[0m] {[34mcli_action_loggers.py:[0m105} WARNING[0m - Failed to log action with (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: log
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.170+0000] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - [SQL: INSERT INTO log (dttm, dag_id, task_id, event, execution_date, owner, extra) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.170+0000] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - [parameters: ('2022-10-13 08:16:39.135929', None, None, 'cli_cleanup_tables', None, 'airflow', '{"host_name": "hostname", "full_command": "[\'/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow\', \'db\', \'clean\', \'--clean-before-timestamp\', \'2022-08-14\', \'-y\']"}')]
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.170+0000] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)[0m
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.170+0000] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - [[34m2022-10-13 08:16:39,170[0m] {[34mdb_cleanup.py:[0m354} WARNING[0m - Table callback_request not found.  Skipping.[0m
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.171+0000] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - [[34m2022-10-13 08:16:39,170[0m] {[34mdb_cleanup.py:[0m354} WARNING[0m - Table celery_taskmeta not found.  Skipping.[0m
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.171+0000] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - [[34m2022-10-13 08:16:39,170[0m] {[34mdb_cleanup.py:[0m354} WARNING[0m - Table celery_tasksetmeta not found.  Skipping.[0m
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.171+0000] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - [[34m2022-10-13 08:16:39,170[0m] {[34mdb_cleanup.py:[0m354} WARNING[0m - Table dag not found.  Skipping.[0m
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.171+0000] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - [[34m2022-10-13 08:16:39,171[0m] {[34mdb_cleanup.py:[0m354} WARNING[0m - Table dag_run not found.  Skipping.[0m
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.172+0000] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - [[34m2022-10-13 08:16:39,171[0m] {[34mdb_cleanup.py:[0m354} WARNING[0m - Table import_error not found.  Skipping.[0m
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.172+0000] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - [[34m2022-10-13 08:16:39,171[0m] {[34mdb_cleanup.py:[0m354} WARNING[0m - Table job not found.  Skipping.[0m
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.172+0000] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - [[34m2022-10-13 08:16:39,171[0m] {[34mdb_cleanup.py:[0m354} WARNING[0m - Table log not found.  Skipping.[0m
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.172+0000] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - [[34m2022-10-13 08:16:39,171[0m] {[34mdb_cleanup.py:[0m354} WARNING[0m - Table rendered_task_instance_fields not found.  Skipping.[0m
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.173+0000] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - [[34m2022-10-13 08:16:39,171[0m] {[34mdb_cleanup.py:[0m354} WARNING[0m - Table sensor_instance not found.  Skipping.[0m
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.173+0000] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - [[34m2022-10-13 08:16:39,171[0m] {[34mdb_cleanup.py:[0m354} WARNING[0m - Table sla_miss not found.  Skipping.[0m
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.173+0000] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - [[34m2022-10-13 08:16:39,171[0m] {[34mdb_cleanup.py:[0m354} WARNING[0m - Table task_fail not found.  Skipping.[0m
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.173+0000] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - [[34m2022-10-13 08:16:39,171[0m] {[34mdb_cleanup.py:[0m354} WARNING[0m - Table task_instance not found.  Skipping.[0m
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.174+0000] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - [[34m2022-10-13 08:16:39,171[0m] {[34mdb_cleanup.py:[0m354} WARNING[0m - Table task_reschedule not found.  Skipping.[0m
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.174+0000] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - [[34m2022-10-13 08:16:39,171[0m] {[34mdb_cleanup.py:[0m354} WARNING[0m - Table xcom not found.  Skipping.[0m
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.334+0000] {subprocess.py:96} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.438+0000] {taskinstance.py:1412} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. <dag_id etc>
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.519+0000] {local_task_job.py:156} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2022-10-13T08:16:39.681+0000] {local_task_job.py:279} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Does anybody have some guidance on how to get the db clean command working in a DAG?

Comment: pass "AIRFLOW_HOME" in your environment and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, that the `BashOperator` does not expose the full environment to the task. The airflow cli does not know your connection string to your DB and does a fallback to sqlite3, which we see here:

> Failed to log action with (sqlite3.OperationalError)

You need to provide `AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN` to the `BashOperator` environment. In case it does not exist as env-var (check with printenv), because you have the config in `airflow.cfg` only, then you need to create it.

Example:

```py
env = {
  "clean_before_timestamp": CLEAN_BEFORE_TIMESTAMP,
  "PATH": os.getenv("PATH"),
  "AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN": os.getenv("AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN")
},
```

Works for me :)

Link:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#sql-alchemy-conn